# React: keep getting 'module not found' when requiring react-lazy-load

Tags: reactjs, lazy-loading

I am trying to use React Lazy Load (https://github.com/loktar00/react-lazy-load) .  I am requiring it with:
 `var LazyLoad = require('react-lazy-load').default;`   I'm using `default` based off of this: https://github.com/loktar00/react-lazy-load/issues/86 .  Also, it doesn't work at all without .default at the end.
But I'm still getting `newBundle.js:1 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module 'react-lazy-load'` with just requiring it.  Any ideas why?

EDIT: Forgot to mention I've already installed it with `npm install --save react-lazy-load` at the very beginning and it's showing in my package.json so I know it's there.

EDIT:  Below are my packages already installed in package.json (NOT using webpack, using browserify)

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "colors": "1.1.2",
    "dotenv": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "1.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "6.1.2",
    "expect": "1.20.2",
    "mocha": "3.0.2",
    "vinyl-buffer": "1.0.0",
    "vinyl-source-stream": "1.1.0",
    "yargs": "5.0.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "analytics-node": "3.2.0",
    "autoprefixer": "7.2.3",
    "babel-cli": "6.26.0",
    "babel-core": "6.14.0",
    "babel-plugin-react-transform": "2.0.2",
    "babel-plugin-transform-runtime": "6.12.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "6.14.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "6.11.1",
    "babelify": "7.3.0",
    "bluebird": "3.5.1",
    "body-parser": "1.18.2",
    "bootstrap": "git://github.com/tradecoffee/bootstrap.git#v3.3.7-custom",
    "braintree-web": "3.26.0",
    "browserify": "13.1.0",
    "compression": "1.7.2",
    "connect-redis": "3.3.2",
    "cookie-parser": "1.4.3",
    "cors": "2.8.4",
    "create-react-class": "15.6.3",
    "envify": "4.1.0",
    "express": "4.14.0",
    "express-http-proxy": "1.0.0",
    "express-session": "1.15.6",
    "font-awesome": "4.6.3",
    "helmet": "3.9.0",
    "heroku-ssl-redirect": "0.0.4",
    "honeybadger": "1.2.1",
    "honeybadger-js": "0.5.5",
    "jquery": "1.9.1",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.2.0",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "newrelic": "3.3.0",
    "node-sass": "4.1.1",
    "npm-run-all": "3.0.0",
    "onchange": "3.3.0",
    "passport": "0.2.0",
    "passport-http": "0.2.2",
    "postcss": "6.0.14",
    "react": "15.6.2",
    "react-autosuggest": "9.3.2",
    "react-bootstrap": "0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "15.6.2",
    "request": "2.83.0",
    "request-promise": "4.2.2",
    "rimraf": "2.5.4",
    "forge-sha256": "git://github.com/tradecoffee/forge-sha256",
    "uglify-js": "3.2.2",
    "uglifyify": "4.0.5",
    "watchify": "3.11.0",
    "wolfy87-eventemitter": "5.2.4"
  }
```

Comment: seems like you haven't installed the module. try `npm install react-lazy-load`?

Comment: From the error it seems you haven't installed the npm module. Install it using `npm install -S react-lazy-load` or `yarn add react-lazy-load`

Comment: @AseemUpadhyay apologies, yes I've done this step already and it appears in my package.json:     "react-lazy-load": "^3.0.13",

Comment: Can you show us your package.json to see the packages you have installed (this is always useful for these kind of questions)? are you using webpack? if you are, could you show us how you load your modules with you webpack.config?

Comment: @c-chavez editing my question now to show my packages √

Comment: Did you ever manage to fix this? Ran into something similar.

Answer (score 0):

Import it like

```
  import LazyLoad from 'react-lazy-load';
```

Or

```
  var LazyLoad = require('react-lazy-load');
```

Comment: Can you check, when you import with require it will return a default object instead of function so at the end default is required. `require('react-lazy-load').default`. First option will work fine.